# How to set the id of a View in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js

In Backbone.js when I create a view I can initialise the 'class' attribute of it's element as shown below:

```
var newView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'foo'
});
```

Is there a similar way to set the 'id' attribute in a similar way?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
var newView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'foo1',  // or
    tagName: 'foo2', // or ..
    className: 'foo3' // 
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

There is an existing id property you can use. Here's a relevant portion from the docs:

> elview.el All views have a DOM element at all times (the el property),
>   whether they've already been inserted into the page or not. In this
>   fashion, views can be rendered at any time, and inserted into the DOM
>   all at once, in order to get high-performance UI rendering with as few
>   reflows and repaints as possible. **this.el is created from the view's
>   tagName, className, id and attributes properties, if specified.** If
>   not, el is an empty div.

Also, you can bind to an existing element that is already in the HTML if that works better for you.